# React state does not update on time, asynchronous issue

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, state

I've build a web application using React that has user registration.
The user data:

```
{ 
  username: 'string', 
  password: 'string'
}
```

exists in a postgresql database and as state.
I'm trying to handle a case where a user is trying to register with a previously used username.

Here's a screenshot of my ui component and react dev tools :

[image]Here's a summary of how I'm handling the case where a username (i'll use the username 'bob' as seen of the screenshot) has already been used:

1. // Login.js

   The 'Register' `<input>` in the `<Login/>` component (which contains all the .jsx for the ui form seen on the screen) invokes the `userRegister(`) function via an `onClick event`. It receives this function as a prop from my `<App/>` (App.js) component, then the following happens...
2. // App.js

   1 - `userRegister()` is invoked

   2- it invokes 2 functions that check whether the password and username are valid

   3- if they are, it invokes a function to check if the username has already been used by checking if it exists as a record in the postgresql database

   4- it does this by sending an axios request with the current username + password object as params to the '/users' endpoint, written out in my server.js file

   ```
     axios({
         method: 'get',
         url: '/users',
         params: { username: 'string', password: 'string' 
       })
   ```
3. // server.js

   1- the request is received by an express route handler at the '/users' endpoint

   2- inside the route handler, it invokes an imported `getUser()` function from postgres.js that communicates directly with the database

   ```
   const { getData, getUser, addUser } = require('./db/postgres.js');                           
   app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
     getUser(req.query)
   });
   ```
4. // postgres.js

   1- the `getUser()` function sends the following query to the postgres database

   ```
   const getUser = (user) => {
     return client.query(`select * from users where username='${user.username}'`)
   };
   ```
5. after sending that query

   this object should reach the client

   ```
   response.rows: [
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: 'Pi2@' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '8*lA' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '8*lA' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '7&lL' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '*lL0' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: 'mM0)' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '8*fF' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '7&yY' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '55$rR' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '7&yY' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '8*LAAa' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '8*lAa' },
     { id: null, username: 'bob', password: '8*lA' }
   ]
   ```

   which proves that the username does, in fact already exist in the database

   [image]
6. which should, in turn, update the `alreadyRegistered state` to `true` and invoke the alert 'user already exists', but, as demonstrated in the top screenshot, `alreadyRegistered` doesn't update in time

   it DOES show the update in Rect devtools a few ms later[image]

I'm fairly certain that the issue is due to state hooks and lifecycle methods being asynchronous, but with that being said how do I update the alreadyRegisted state to true before the code on line 63 executes? [image]

Here are snippets of the code files working together. Let me know if more information/context is needed

- Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { NavBar, Footer } from'../Imports.js';


const Login = ({ userAuth, getUserAuth, userLogin, authorized, userRegister }) => {
  console.log('userAuth:', userAuth);
  return (
    <div id='login'>
      <NavBar userAuth={userAuth} getUserAuth={getUserAuth} authorized={authorized} />
      <section id='login-main'>
        <form>
          <input type='text' placeholder='username' onChange={() => {getUserAuth({...userAuth, username: event.target.value})}}/>
          <input type='text' placeholder='password'onChange={() => {getUserAuth({...userAuth, password: event.target.value})}}/>
          <input type='submit' value='Login' onClick={() => {event.preventDefault(); userLogin()}}/>
          <input type='submit' value='Register' onClick={() => {event.preventDefault(); userRegister();}}/>
        </form>
      </section>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Login;
```

- App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Router from './Router.js';
const axios = require('axios');

const App = () => {

  // Login/user state
  const [userAuth, getUserAuth] = useState({username: '', password: ''});
  const [authorized, authorizeUser] = useState(false);
  const [alreadyRegistered, userExists] = useState(false);

  // new user register
  const userRegister = () => { // <- 1)
    if (validUsername() && validPassword()) {
      checkIfExists();
      console.log('alreadyRegistered:', alreadyRegistered);
      if (alreadyRegistered) {
        alert('user already exists');
      } else {
        console.log('ERROR: should update alreadyRegistered state to TRUE and invoke ALERT')
      }
    }
  }

// check if username is already registered
  const checkIfExists = () => { // <- 3)
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/users',
      params: userAuth
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.length)
      if (res.data.length) {
        console.log(res.data.length, 'INNER')
        userExists(true);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    })
  }
};
```

- server.js

```
// ----- external modules -----
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const { getData, getUser, addUser } = require('./db/postgres.js');

// check if user exists
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  console.log('req.body:', req.query)
  getUser(req.query)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('response.rows:', response.rows);
    res.send(response.rows);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
});
```

- postgres.js

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const getUser = (user) => {
  return client.query(`select * from users where username='${user.username}'`)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering the state question, it's important to know your application as written is vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead of a template string in your `postgres.js` file, you should use [parameterized queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries).

As for the value of `alreadyRegistered`, you're correct that the issue lies in the asynchronous nature of state hooks.

You can use the `useEffect` function to handle updates to `alreadyRegistered` like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (alreadyRegistered) {
        alert('user already exists');
    } else {
        // create user...
    }
}, [alreadyRegistered]);
```

You could also avoid tracking `alreadyRegistered` in state and just call `checkIfExists` as needed:

```js
// first, remove alreadyRegistered state
const [userAuth, getUserAuth] = useState({username: '', password: ''});
const [authorized, authorizeUser] = useState(false);

// then redefine checkIfExists to return Promise<boolean>
const checkIfExists = async () => {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/users',
      params: userAuth
    })

    return !!res.data.length; // convert fetch result to boolean
}

// then call checkIfExists in userRegister
const userRegister = async () => {
    if (validUsername() && validPassword()) {
      const alreadyRegistered = await checkIfExists();
      if (alreadyRegistered) {
        alert('user already exists');
      } else {
        // handle user creation
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So to my understanding, a parameterized query would be something like VALUES($1, $2) where $1 and $2 would be the parameters. And the template string variables would exist only in the node.js environment thus making it more secure.

Comment: As for useEffect does it work because it's also a hook and therefore asynchronous? Could an alternative be to wrap the conditional in a promise or callback? Another thing I've noticed is that the alreadyRegistered state is only updated the first time I invoke checkIfExists, meaning that I have to refresh the login page every time I want to check if a username has been taken. I think I'm asking too many questions you've answered my original one and thank you. Do you have any resources that I could use to better understand the nature of hooks and lifecycle methods?

Comment: Kinda -- the parameterized query replaces your template string entirely. The $1 and $2 values are injected into the string in a way that prevents malicious users from executing SQL.

`useEffect` works because it is "reactive" meaning it is called when its dependencies (`alreadyRegistered`) are updated. You could define `checkIfExists` as an `async` function that returns a boolean and `await` it instead of updating state (which is probably simpler).

Here's a quick guide for hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html. Also please accept my answer if it's helpful.

Comment: Sure thing, your answer did work. There's just the issue of the `alert()` being invoked only once but that's for another question. I've also noticed that wrapping the hook in a promise works though the issue still persists                                                                            
 `const promise =  () => new Promise (() => {userExists(true);})
        promise()
          .then(() => {alreadyRegistered && alert('user already exists');})`
thank again

Comment: Instead of wrapping your hook in a promise, it might be easier to make `checkIfExists` return a promise instead of updating your component's state. I've updated my answer to include this change.

Comment: Thank you. That solved the alert() issue as well. I'm not sure why it doesn't work the same way with the state hook but I'll investigate that on my own. Appreciate it.